How to get the Data skipped from Storage Transfer Service Job (AWS -> GCP)
I was able to transfer data successfully using GCP Storage Transfer Service from my bucket in AWS to GCP, and I got that there are 17 files skipped because there are files that have the same name in the destination bucket on GCP, 
How to Identify those 17 files?

According to this, As of this writing, we don't have a way to identify skipped files filtered by transfer job.

Did you set up logging before you executed the transfer job? If not, you can view all the failed files by enabling Logging, then, rerun the transfer skipping the already transferred files. You may follow the steps below:
Step 1: Patch the failed TransferJob with a loggingConfig
Step 2: Run the TransferJob again - which should retry all failed objects
Step 3: Read transfer logs to find the names (and details) of all failed objects.
You may view this documentation for more details - Cloud Logging for Storage Transfer Service.

I did set logging but it doesn't show the skipped data, I tried your solution, but it didn't help either, thanks anyway
Do you if there are other docs that I might be missing that could help?
